# How to make a checkbox required with ng-messages and ionic?

Tags: angularjs, html, forms, ionic-framework

I am making a form on my app. Cordova CLI 8.0, Ionic 1.3.5, AngularJS 1.5.

I want to make a checkbox required on my form.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<ion-checkbox name="entry.exportcode" ng-model="entry.value" ng-required="entry.mandatory === '1'">{{ entry.itemlabel }}</ion-checkbox>
<div ng-messages="form.templateForm[entry.exportcode].$error">
    <div class="form-error" ng-message="required"><span ng-i18next="VALIDATION_REQUIRED_FIELD"></span></div>
</div>
```

The mandatory part is ignored and I cannot see any error messages.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing quotes in `ng-messages`

It should be `ng-messages="form.templateForm['entry.exportcode'].$error"` not `ng-messages="form.templateForm[entry.exportcode].$error"`

```
<ion-checkbox name="entry.exportcode" ng-model="entry.value" ng-required="entry.mandatory === '1'">{{ entry.itemlabel }}</ion-checkbox>
<div ng-messages="form.templateForm['entry.exportcode'].$error">
    <div class="form-error" ng-message="required"><span ng-i18next="VALIDATION_REQUIRED_FIELD"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But mine is a variable value not a string.

Comment: Your `name` attribute in `ion-checkbox` is string not variable. Check in dev tool you will see it as is. and the same should be used for checking errors.

Comment: My form is dynamically generated so I need it to be a variable.

Comment: Nevermind you were right I got it to work! Thanks very much!